# Convert a JSON Object to an index based JSON Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object in the below format which I want to convert into a JSON array. I have tried multiple ways to achieve this, but I can not get success.

```js
{
   "name":{
      "0":"mike",
      "1":"george",
      "2":"Andrew"
   },
   "category":{
      "0":"A",
      "1":"B",
      "2":"C"
   }
}
```

The output would be like this:

```js
{
   "0":{
      "name":"mike",
      "category":"A"
   },
   "1":{
      "name":"george",
      "category":"B"
   },
   "2":{
      "name":"andrew",
      "category":"C"
   }
}
```

I am new to JSON. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please share what you have already tried, and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Hi BenM i updated the question ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const obj = {
  name: {
    "0": "mike",
    "1": "george",
    "2": "Andrew",
  },
  category: {
    "0": "A",
    "1": "B",
    "2": "C",
  },
};
const props = Object.keys(obj);
const result = props.reduce((acc, key) => {
  Object.entries(obj[key]).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (!acc[k]) acc[k] = Object.fromEntries(props.map((p) => [p, ""]));
    acc[k][key] = v;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```